# Bump function that maximizes at the compact set

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Given $K\subset U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open, is there a bump function $\phi$ st

$\bullet\quad\phi(x)=1$, for $x\in K$;

$\bullet\quad\phi(x)=0$, for $x\in U^c$;

$\bullet\quad 0\le \phi(x)<1$, for $x\in U\backslash K$?

See, $\phi$ is almost an ususal bump function, but it maximizes only on $K$.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context for how you found this problem?

Comment: Is $\phi$ smooth? For Lipschitz, you can do something with $dist(x, K)$ so that your function only maximizes at $K$.

Comment: @Jose27 So, $\phi$ must actually be $C^{\infty}$. Here's a link for what i mean by "an usual bump function" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function